# Background size getting changed

Tags: android, user-interface, android-layout

I'm changing Background color of a button programmatically as below

```
     Button button =(Button)findViewById(R.id.one);
    button.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFF0000);
```

But after this the size of button getting increased.. Im using relative layout in UI.

Comment: Text color isn't background color btw.

Comment: as you mentioned in question you are changing Background color and in code you set the properties for button.setTextColor(0xFFFF0000)?

Comment: Sorry im using button.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFF0000); i edited it now please have a look

Comment: So what's the question? "Why?" or "How to keep it exactly the same size?" And how much is it getting increased?

Comment: yup thats the question, how to keep it in same size as before even if i change color..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Default button background drawable has some kind of margins. These margins are just transparent pixels on the sides of the image. When you set background color for a button these margins disappear because the whole rectangle of the button is filled with the color.

Comment: If i change color as below its not affecting button size. But i didnt got what this is doin exactly :
button.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFFFF0000, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);

Comment: It means that you remove green and blue components for each pixel of button's background so the button must be red.