# Height mismatch for Normal Button and Custom Background Button in Android

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-button, android-custom-drawable

I tried to set different background color for button. But the height will differs when compared to Normal and Custom Button.

[image]

**layout file:**

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_normal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Normal" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_custon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_background"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/btn_normal"
        android:text="Custom"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
```

**custom_bbackground.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape >
            <corners android:radius="6dp" />
            <solid android:color="#026267"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="6dp" />
            <solid android:color="#026267"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item >
        <shape >
            <corners android:radius="6dp" />
            <solid android:color="#026267" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the new release v23.0.0 of the `AppCompat` library it is now possible to create Material Design Buttons for Lollipop and Pre-Lollipop devices.

If you just want to define the color of all Buttons you can set a special theme property called `colorButtonNormal`:

Add this line to your parent theme under `styles.xml`

```
<item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/yourColor</item>
```

for more information refer [this](http://manuel-ohlendorf.de/blog/2015/09/03/material-design-buttons-with-appcompat/)

**EDIT:**

Making custom theme for button will do the trick.

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/yourcolor</item>
</style>
```

and in use this like.

```
<Button android:theme="@style/CustomTheme"/>
```

***Note:*** make sure you are using `Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored` as parent.

Happy Coding..

Comment: Yeah theme can help full. But in Above scenario I need to use one custom color button and one default button. Can you suggest for this?

Comment: This [link](http://manuel-ohlendorf.de/blog/2015/09/03/material-design-buttons-with-appcompat/) helpfull. Thanks @vrund purohit

Comment: `parent=""` would be correct. Stop mixing *themes* and *styles* together, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to assign **android:layout_height="match_parent"** for both buttons and the main layout in which you have put both button set it's height as wrap content like **android:layout_height="wrap_content"**

Answer (score -1):

Default button background drawable has some kind of margins. These margins are just transparent pixels on the sides of the image. When you set background color for a button these margins disappear because the whole rectangle of the button is filled with the color.[please see this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7471064/background-size-getting-changed)

Comment: Ok then where is the solution?

Comment: dude solution is change normal button to custom button and use normal button background color.simple

Comment: Why I need to change normal Button. I need custom button as like normal button.